# Jump to a different location of the page when id or name does not exist

Tags: jquery, html, css

What I have is a very long textual content page

```
<p class="parahead">401. Heading </p>
<p>other html content</p>
<p class="c2">some more data</P>
...
<p class="parahead">402. Another heading </p>
<p>other html content</p>
...
```

Adding Id or name property for each of these paragraph tags is not an option at all. I have jquery in the page. Is it possible to make a page jump based on the content of the paragraph? I do not want to add any other tags to this html dynamically as it will slow down the page load

**update:**
More information about the problem. I have two html files. Say A and B. A is the source file and B has some explanations about A. At the scroll event of A, I can get the content/id of the current paragraph in view port. When user clicks on a button of the wrapper around A, user should be taken to the appropriate section on B (which has explanations of A)

Comment: Yes it's possible. How are you getting the text to find, under what event should the jump happen and have you at least made an attempt to solve this yourself?

Comment: As Rory says, it's definitely possible, but it'd be much easier if you uniquely tag each element. Otherwise it's going to be messy, especially if there isn't any sort of constant _theme_ of the content of the headers.

Comment: Rory and @butler, it is not possible to edit this html, considering the size of the file and content. Only option i see is to add a dynamic span with auto incrementing id somehow at page load and then use that for the page jump

Comment: Well don't have a choice really other than to edit the HTML, even to add some javascript. But here's an idea. - 

Save the result of `document.getElementsByClass('Parahead')` to a list, and every time you need to jump to the next section, increment a value (from 0) then using the incremented value as an index, scroll to the next item in the list.

Comment: @Butler1233, updated the question. I have added more info as Rory requested about the event this needs to be fired.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do it like this:

```
//Onclick the paragraph
$('.parahead').click( function(){

//Select the number inside the paragraph
var page = $(this).text().split(".");

//Redirect to e.g. 401.html
window.location.replace("./" + page[0] + ".html");
});
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to

> I do not want to add any other tags to this html dynamically as it will slow down the page load

I end up adding a dynamic element at page load.

```
$(function(){
        addTags();
        function addTags(){
        $('.parahead').each(function (){
            var id = parseInt($(this).text());
            console.log(id);
            $(this).after("<span name='parahead" + id +"'></span>");
        });
        }
});
```